# Couldn't Save Field

Tags: templating, matrix, field

I am editing an already existing field in Craft. When I go to save, I get an error message that says "Couldn't Save Field", and the block type is highlighted in red. The field type is a Matrix that contains a rich text field, a Link It field, and an image field.

I am on Craft CMS 2.6.2949.

Any ideas on what could be causing this error?

---

**Edit: Additional Info**

Below is a screenshot of my Matrix field + child fields. I get the error only when I use one of our entry types as the Link Type.

[image]

Comment: If you click the red block type, find the red field. There should be an error message there.

Comment: Thanks @LindseyD - when I click the red block type, there are no fields that are being highlighted in red. Further update: When I try to create a new Matrix field, I am able to save until I add a Link It field type to the Matrix. When I add a Link It field, it gives me the error again ("Couldn't Save Field").

Comment: What is the handle for your Link It field? Certain handles (like "link" or "url") are restricted words and can't be used.

Comment: I've tried several things: "clientwebsite", "link", "test"...

Comment: Additionally, I am able to create a Link It field by itself, but not able to create or save a Matrix field containing a Link It field type.

Comment: Add a screenshot of your Matrix field settings to the question. Try to highlight the Link It field in particular.

Comment: Reproduce the issue, then check your `craft/storage/runtime/logs` files for either `[error]` or `[warning]` and see if anything is being logged.

Comment: @LindseyD, I've added a screenshot + some additional info to my original question.

Comment: Thanks, @Brad Bell. We've been looking at the runtime logs and there are no issues being logged as a result of this.

Comment: Possibly a Link It bug?  There's a vaguely similar sounding issue already created here: https://github.com/fruitstudios/LinkIt/issues/35

Comment: @BradBell I think you are on to something here. We've concluded that it is most likely a Link It bug, and we are transitioning out of using this field type as it is preventing us from making changes. If you will make your comment as an answer, I'd like to mark it as such.

Comment: @jennetcetera Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's entirely possible it's a [Link It](https://github.com/fruitstudios/LinkIt/) bug. There is a vaguely similar sounding issue already created here: https://github.com/fruitstudios/LinkIt/issues/35

Comment: Thank you! We've concluded that it is most likely a Link It bug, and we are transitioning out of using this field type as it is preventing us from making changes.